# Downloading and executing scripts in supported browsers only?

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry, this is almost certainly a duplicate, but I've been searching StackOverflow and haven't been able to find the answer. Hopefully if I phrase it in the most general terms I can, it will help someone else in the future.

I'm including some scripts in my web page which work awesomely in Chrome/FF/Opera/Safari/IE9, but are not compatible with IE8 or below (for info, it's the awesome [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)).

How can I use make sure that the page fails gracefully in IE<9?

Ideally I would prefer for IE<9 users

- not to download D3.js external scripts at all and
- to show them a 'Sorry, this won't work for you' message in my page script, rather than attempting to use the D3 libraries and causing a JavaScript error.

Current code in the HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mylocal.js"></script>
```

And in the JavaScript file, from the opening line:

```
var vis = d3.select("#vis")
.append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h)
.append("svg:g");
// etc
```

How should I change these to make sure that only browsers that support D3 will download and try to execute it?

Comment: Disable them from downloading can be done this way: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: how about feature detection for svg support and then lazy load the libary?

Comment: @Burntime actually that would be preferable I guess, because it would handle any other browsers that don't do SVG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [IE conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<p>Sorry, this won't work for you</p>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mylocal.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Just to save a click, here is an example: `<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/excanvas-modified.js"></script><![endif]-->`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIEVersion(){
   var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
   var msie = ua.indexOf ("MSIE ");

   if (msie > 0)      
       return parseInt(ua.substring(msie+5, ua.indexOf (".", msie )));   // If Internet Explorer, return version number
   else                 
     return 10;   // If another browser, return 10
} 

if(getIEVersion() < 9 ){
     alert("Sorry, this won't work for you");
}else{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mylocal.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: wouldn't work, assume you were in FF you'd get the alert too, since your parse function returns 0 (<9) for non-ie browsers